# How can i find the closest match

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, string-matching

I am matching values which is slightly different in that case how can i find the closest match

In this example everything has very close relationship but how can my script find a match

Eg script which i wrote

```
a = ["12,th 3rd street","6th avenue 3r cross","6th street pan,CA","345 hoston road CA","345 hoston road CA"]
b = ["12,th 3rd st","6th av 3rd crs","6th street pan CA WY","345 hoston road, CA","345 hoston road,CA"]
for s in a:
    for v in b:
        if s == v:
            python s
```

If you see both this array only some worrs will differ

```
a = ["12,th 3rd street","6th avenue 3r cross","6th street pan,CA","345 hoston road CA","345 hoston road CA"]
    b = ["12,th 3rd st","6th av 3rd crs","6th street pan CA WY","345 hoston road, CA","345 hoston road,CA"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need some predefined words for matching `this or that`.

```
for eg., {cross:{cr,crs}, avenue:{av,avn}}
```

you can match the some continuous strings directly

```
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        if i in j or j in i:
            print (i,j)
```

This gives,

`12,th 3rd street` `12,th 3rd st`

to match other cases use the dictionary to select any value using key or vice versa.